# What is the difference between Clock.systemUTC() and Clock.systemDefaultZone()?

Tags: java, datetime

I'm looking at the [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class from java so that I can inject it as a dependency for better testability. But I don't understand the difference between the two methods `systemUTC` and `systemDefaultZone`. The `Instant.now()` seems to be internally using `systemUTC` clock whereas `YearMonth.now()` uses the `systemDefaultZone` clock. I already read the javadoc but it wasn't very clear to me.

I have code that use `Instant.now()` and `YearMonth.now()` and would like to understand the difference between the two clocks with some examples where using each the clocks wrongly can lead to a problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of the `instant` method of the two clocks returned by `Clock.systemUTC` and `Clock.systemDefaultZone`, they will do the same thing. Both of their documentation says that the clocks are "based on the best available system clock". So creating `Instant`s using the clocks will always give you the same instant.

The difference in behaviour comes when you try to create a date or time. `systemUTC` does this:

> Conversion from instant to date or time uses the UTC time-zone.

Whereas `systemDefaultZone` does this:

> converting to date and time using the default time-zone.

So although both will return the same instant if you ask them what the current instant is, they will not necessarily return the same `LocalDateTime`, or `LocalDate`, or `ZonedDateTime`. For example, suppose my system timezone is `Asia/Shanghai`, which is at an offset of UTC+8 all year round. And it is now 5 am on 2020-07-29 in Shanghai. If I do `LocalDate.now(Clock.systemUTC())`, it will tell me `2020-07-28`, because it's still the 28th in the UTC timezone. If I do `LocalDate.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone())`, however, it will tell me `2020-07-29`, because it is 2020-07-29 in Shanghai (which is the system timezone).

Now you should see why the parameterless `now` of date/time related classes use `systemDefaultZone`. It would be weird if I did `LocalTime.now()` in Shanghai and saw a time that's 8 hours earlier!